# Representing Euler Angles in terms of Rotation Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, transformation, angle

Matrices keep the original frame of reference. So when I rotate, then shear, the second shear would be in terms of the original frame and not the rotated frame.

However, in Euler angles, when I rotate in the x, then rotate in the z, the rotation in the z would be with respect to the new frame.

Here was my attempt to represent Euler Angles with rotation matrices:

$$R_x, R_y, R_z$$ are rotations around the fixed x-axis, y-axis, and z-axis.

First I rotate with around the x-axis:
$$R_x$$
Then I rotate around the y-axis, but in the new frame:

$$(R_x R_y R_x^{-1}) R_x = R_xR_y$$

And finally around the z axis in the newest frame:

$$(R_xR_yR_zR_y^{-1}R_x^{-1})R_xR_y=R_xR_yR_z$$

Which is basically matrix rotation in reverse. Is there something wrong? It doesn't feel right.

Comment: what you describe is an alternative to "Euler angles" called Tait-Bryan angles.

Comment: @Habouz You might find [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Conversion_formulae_between_formalisms) to be helpful